# Improved ESP32-CAM?

Tags: esp32

Is there something better than the ESP32-CAM board? In therms of image quality and streaming capabilities? To make a good quality WiFi camera.

EDIT:
To be used in DIY projects like the ESP32-CAM, a small board with a small camera.
At least WXGA (1280x800) at 60 frames, ideally 1080P (1920x1080) without image jumping and a good quality lens with less blur and vignetting then ESP32-CAM camera.

Comment: There are definitely "better" things around if you define which aspects these should be better in.

Comment: At least WXGA (1280x800) at 60 frames, ideally 1080P (1920x1080) without image jumping and a good quality lens with less blur and vignetting then ESP32-CAM camera.

Comment: Part/equipment selection questions are off topic.  Note that a router-style Embedded Linux booting from robust NOR flash can probably host any USB camera with a standard-ish interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider a [*Raspberry Pi*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) with the new [HQ camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/) they released a couple months ago:

[image: rpi camera hq]

Comment: Of course an SD-card based pi is in a very different category than a NOR-flash-based ESP32 in terms of complexity and robustness of state.

Comment: in one case you have a whole operating system, which might be an advantage or a disadvantage. provided that you can program a script that runs on the rpi, you can have a functionally equivalent module

Comment: There are ways to get a full operating system in a more robust form, a more power mangeable form, etc. - the pi was really designed to be a set top box, not an embedded system.  Anyway shopping questions are off topic to begin with.

Comment: At that price, might as well get a finished product.